# How dangerous are high voltage batteries in water?

Tags: batteries, water

I am currently building an electric surfboard. The power source will be 16 li ion batteries in series to make a nominal 57.6 volts. My question is pertaining to the possibility of water flooding the electronics enclosure and creating a situation where I can be electrocuted. If the compartment were to be completely filled with water around the batteries and my feet somehow bridged a connection to the compartment would current flow through me or are batteries in that situation grounded to their own negative terminal? Thanks in advance

Comment: Even 10mA passing through your body will make your muscles get hard and because u will be wet the resistance of your body will drop.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the li ion in salt water, than the voltage.  [Lithium Batteries Dropped in Water! TKOR Exploding Lithium Battery Experiment!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTJh_bzI0QQ)

Comment: Batteries have been used in underwater equipment for centuries. You can get sealed batteries like [this](http://www.seascooterexpress.com/store/product104.html). Show us when you have built that flying surf board.

Answer (score 1):

The current will find its lowest impedance path. If that happens to be your body (a good possibility, considering salt water) then it could pose a hazard.

As a reference, body salinity is about 0.4%. Seawater is about 3.5%. So saltwater is a much better conductor than the human body.

One thought would be to have a grounding area adjacent to the battery. Then any stray current would tend to shunt through the saltwater directly to that ground.

Even still, with immersion, even a modest voltage can cause muscle contractions. More here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2763825/

Comment: Thank you for the response, does the battery negative terminal not serve as its own ground if current were to flow freely around in that situation?

Comment: "Ground" just means an arbitrary 0V reference and PE is a safety reference. <50V is considered low voltage and is used on telephone lines.  But 9V battery on your tongue is a zinger.

Comment: One other thought: enhance the battery OV/UV disconnect with something that detects flooding. Then the battery will shut off in the presence of water.

Comment: Yeah I was starting to go along that route until I realized if the entire battery gets submerged there is no real way to "shut it off" I was watching eltroboom on youtube who did an experiment putting live ac wires in water and since they were close the current almost completely flowed from one to the other. I was wondering if batteries worked the same way and not killing me in the process of a major failure.

Comment: If the battery and protection is in its own watertight enclosure then that would be better. The shutoff could be just a simple set of contacts that detect moisture.

Answer (score 1):

The chances of you getting in the loop of the electrical path are slim unless you are really careless with wiring the controls.

But the chances that the design will fail from seepage, corrosion etc are pretty high unless you have submarine design experience and use lubricated oil / water seals on every interface to exposed water including motor shaft.

Most plastic is hygroscopic and  Teflon is used to equalize air pressure for H2 for SLA batteries.

Traxxas LiPo batteries are water resistant  but not rated under pressure.

Good luck .

Comment: Thank you for the response, I guess my real question is would the current in that situation flow to the battery negative wires as that would be where it wants to go anyway, or would it somehow want to flow through my feet and too whatever body of water I am on?

Comment: I've been in the water when lightning struck not too far away.  The only mild shock I got from the million Volts and amps was from the long wire I was holding by induction , sitting in a boat 1/4m away, doing seismic research on islands.  Current will flow thru the paths of least resistance.  I'm assuming you aren't touching non-waterproof contaminated wires open circuit trying to bridge the circuit.